# knockout - initial value for checked binding in radio button

Tags: knockout.js

I wonder why in the following example, the radiobuttons do not get checked by default, even though they were bound to the observable `ch` property that was initialized as `true`.

```
 <div data-bind="foreach : boxList">
<span data-bind="text : name"></span>
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="true" data-bind="checked : ch"/>

</div>
```

---

```
 var viewModel = function() {
   this.boxList = [ 
     { name : 'T1', ch : ko.observable("true")},
     { name : 'T2', ch : ko.observable("true")}
   ];

 }

 ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bspsack5/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Knockout assumes that a radio button is checked if its `value` attribute matches the value of the observable to which its checked binding is connected. In other words, if the value of your radio is `left`, then it will be checked if Knockout finds the value `"left"` in the observable which is assigned to the `checked: someObservable` binding expression. This is thoroughly discussed on the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

You can find a working modification of your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bspsack5/8/). All that happens is that a property is defined on the viewmodel:

```
this.selectedValue = ko.observable('A');
```

which is then used in the `checked` binding expression. So `checked` "holds the choice of the user", while the `value` binding expression should point to the actual value used by the input field which Knockout uses to toggle the `checked` state:

```
data-bind="checked : $parent.selectedValue, value: value"
```

Comment: Thanks. I just adjusted the value to "true" and the initialization of the ko.observable also with the string "true", but still it works only for the last element in the list.

Comment: Because radios which share the same `name` attribute are mutually exclusive, i.e., radios in the same form with the same `name` cannot be checked at the same time. If you want multiple items to be checked, you need to use checkboxes, not radios.

Comment: You are welcome. I've also updated the fiddle to use booleans as you intended.